# Why does my program stop after passing data from c++ dll to c# several times? (There's no error message)

Tags: c#, c++, dll

I'm working on a project which required a dll file for another program written in c# to use (I'm not very familiar with the usage of C++/C#). After finishing the development(?) of the dll file, I started its testing process(run the function call from dll in C# for many times to ensure it works fine). I've asked the way to pass data from C++ to C# [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58271603/how-to-pass-multiple-cvmat-from-c-dll-to-opencvsharp-mat-c-sharp-properly), and the problem is, **the program will stop without any error message(I've put try catch in my program) *after calling it over 2 times***.

[image]

I've seen a saying that if there's a memory corruption, the program will stop at a very normal line(e.g. std::cout << ...). I think my situation is similar to that saying...

And here's my code structure...

```
//dll.hpp
extern "C" LIB_API void inference(unsigned char* img_pointer, long data_len, cv::Mat*& res, int& img_count, int& mat_type_size, double params[2]);
extern "C" LIB_API void clear_mem(cv::Mat* res);

//dll.cpp
LIB_API void inference(unsigned char* img_pointer, long data_len, cv::Mat*& res, int& img_count, int& mat_type_size, double params[2])
{
    try
    {
        img_count = 8;
        mat_type_size = sizeof(cv::Mat);
        res = new cv::Mat[img_count];
        cv::Mat& img1 = res[0];
        cv::Mat& img2 = res[1];
        cv::Mat& img3 = res[2];
        cv::Mat& img4 = res[3];
        cv::Mat& img5 = res[4];
        cv::Mat& img6 = res[5];
        cv::Mat& img7 = res[6];
        cv::Mat& img8 = res[7];

        //some process to update img1~img8

        std::cout << "res->" << res << std::endl;
        std::cout << "===== finish inference process ===== >> " << (std::clock() - t_inf1) / (double)CLOCKS_PER_SEC << " s" << std::endl;

    }
    catch (const std::runtime_error& re)
    {
        std::cerr << "*** Runtime error: " << re.what() << std::endl;
        return;
    }
    catch (const std::exception& ex)
    {
        std::cerr << "*** Error occurred: " << ex.what() << std::endl;
        return;
    }
    catch (...)
    {
        std::cerr << "*** Unknown failure occurred... Possible memory corruption" << std::endl;
        return;
    }

}

LIB_API void clear_mem(cv::Mat* res)
{
    try
    {
        std::cout << ">> In 'clear_mem'...." << std::endl;
        std::cout << "res in clear_mem->" << res << std::endl;
        delete[] res;
        std::cout << ">> finish deleting res...." << std::endl;
    }
    catch (const std::runtime_error& re)
    {
        std::cerr << "*** Runtime error: " << re.what() << std::endl;
        return;
    }
    catch (const std::exception& ex)
    {
        std::cerr << "*** Error occurred: " << ex.what() << std::endl;
        return;
    }
    catch (...)
    {
        std::cerr << "*** Unknown failure occurred... Possible memory corruption" << std::endl;
        return;
    }
}

//test.cs
namespace Test_Unet_Console
{
    class Program
    {
        [DllImport(@"D:\Coco\Code\C_plus_plus\unet_cpp_dll\x64\Release\unet_cpp_dll.dll")]
        private static extern void inference(byte[] img, long data_len, out IntPtr images, ref int img_count, out int mat_type_size,
                                            [In, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPArray, SizeConst = 3)]double[] param);
        [DllImport(@"D:\Coco\Code\C_plus_plus\unet_cpp_dll\x64\Release\unet_cpp_dll.dll")]
        private static extern void init_inference();

        [DllImport(@"D:\Coco\Code\C_plus_plus\unet_cpp_dll\x64\Release\unet_cpp_dll.dll")]
        private static extern void clear_mem(IntPtr images);

        static void Cppdll_inf(Bitmap image, out List<Mat> output_pic, double[] param, out IntPtr imgPtrs)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("before fmt");
            ImageFormat fmt = new ImageFormat(image.RawFormat.Guid);
            Console.WriteLine("before imageCodecInfo");
            var imageCodecInfo = ImageCodecInfo.GetImageEncoders().FirstOrDefault(codec => codec.FormatID == image.RawFormat.Guid);
            //this is for situations, where the image is not read from disk, and is stored in the memory(e.g. image comes from a camera or snapshot)
            if (imageCodecInfo == null)
            {
                fmt = ImageFormat.Jpeg;
                Console.WriteLine("C# - imageCodecInfo is null");
            }
            Console.WriteLine("before MemoryStream");
            using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
            {
                try
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("C# - before image.Save");
                    image.Save(ms, fmt);
                    Console.WriteLine("C# - finish image.Save");
                    byte[] image_byte_array = ms.ToArray();
                    Console.WriteLine("C# - finish reading pic");

                    int imgCount = 0;

                    inference(image_byte_array, ms.Length, out var imgPtrs, ref imgCount, out var matTypeSize, param);
                    output_pic = new List<Mat>();
                    for (int i = 0; i < imgCount; i++)
                    {
                        output_pic.Add(new Mat(IntPtr.Add(imgPtrs, i * matTypeSize)));
                    }
                    Console.WriteLine("finish getting value from imgPtrs.....");

                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    throw ex;
                }
            }
        }

        // I've tried to add this in my code, but it will cause some error(I didn't record it...)
        static void clear() 
        {

            Console.WriteLine("start gc collect");
            GC.Collect();
            GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
            Console.WriteLine("finish gc collect in clear");
        }

        static void show_result(List<Mat> pic_list)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < pic_list.Count; i++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(i);
                Cv2.ImShow("test", pic_list[i]);
                Cv2.WaitKey(500);
            }
            Cv2.DestroyAllWindows();
            Console.WriteLine("finish showing pic");
        }


        static void Main()
        {
            Bitmap image1 = new Bitmap("C:\\Users\\Coco\\Desktop\\(3).png");
            double[] param = { 0.7, 20 }; //{ VI_threshold, area_threshold }
            Console.WriteLine(">>> Initializing from C# =======");
            init_inference(); // >> initialization of models
            Console.WriteLine(">>> Finish initializing from C# ======");

            for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(i);
                List<Mat> result;
                IntPtr imgPtrs;
                Cppdll_inf(image1, out result, param, out imgPtrs); // inference of picture
                Console.WriteLine(">>> Finish image1 C# ======");
                show_result(result); // showing pic to check if result is correct
                clear_mem(imgPtrs); //  clean the memory send from dll(?
                result.Clear(); 
                Console.WriteLine(">>> Finish result.Clear() ======");
                Console.WriteLine("================================");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I've tried not to return the result from dll to C#, it can run about 100 times(the maximum I've tested). So I think the problem might be the process when passing data from dll to C#...

By the way, here's my memory usage when running the program...
[image]

I've searched many info on the internet, but I still have no idea how to fix this problem, so any advise or help is really appreciated!

(Thanks in advance for finish reading my messy question description! )

Comment: `LIB_API void inference(cv::Mat*& res, int& img_count, int& mat_type_size, double params[2])`
{
* -- Never use reference parameters in a DLL function that is meant to be used by other languages. A reference is a C++ entity, only known by the C++ language and by the C++ compiler version being used.  Use pointers if you need to, but never references.

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply! I'll try to revise my code with all pointers...

Comment: The C++ runtime can failfast a program on gross errors.  The program exit code gives an indication, but be sure to enable unmanaged debugging so you have something to look at.  Project > Properties > Debug tab.  And do consider thoroughly testing the C++ code before you try to pinvoke it, add unit tests.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, I'm still working on the problem... I've tried to run my code in debug mode, it gave out some error code which representing something like memory crush(?). I think I know which line of code cause this `output_pic.Add(new Mat(IntPtr.Add(imgPtrs, i * matTypeSize)));`, but I still don't know how to get rid of it, I'll keep working on it, thanks for your advice!

Comment: I think I have the same problem. When I iterated to call to get multiple mats and it suddenly died without any error message. Did you solve this issue?

Comment: Hi, sorry I forgot to update the answer, I'll give a brief answer here. In my experience on this project, it can be seen as two cases. If you didn't use any additional module(such as cognex, halcon...etc.), you can call `delete[ ] cv::Mat* ` from C# to avoid this from happening(reference [here](https://ppt.cc/fCf4px)). On the other hand, you can rewrite your C# code with the structure like [IDisposable class](https://ppt.cc/fyW2vx)(Sorry I only have Chinese material, you can search for more info), this can ensure your memory are deleted correctly after every run. Hope this help, good luck!

Comment: I quite appreciate your kindness. Just for your information, I iterated it over 3000 times then I tried to use `delete[ ] cv::Mat *`, and it stopped again. So now I'm trying IDsposable class now. Thanks :)

Comment: Sorry I didn't express clearly, you can try to call `delete[] cv::Mat*` _**every time** after receiving Mat from dll_. Since if you `new` an object in c++, you have to use this way to delete one(I don't know if i'm correct...). And it seems like you have new many objects but only call one delete(?) from your description. If I it's my misunderstood, just forget about it~

Answer (score 0):

It's been quite long not recording the answer of this question...

There are two ways to handle this(in my experience):

1. Adding a function with doing `delete[] cv::Mat*` in your cpp, call this function every time after you received a `Mat*` from dll
2. Using [IDisposable Class](https://dotblogs.com.tw/larrynung/2011/03/10/21774) in C#'s calling with DLL function

(Imagine like it kills itself after every run with this syntax)

(This is Chinese material, but I think it's pretty clear with its
example code)